# Can I get MSBuild output from CCNet api?

Tags: asp.net, cruisecontrol.net

I am building an asp.net shell on top of CCNet 1.5, where I send commands like force build to CCNet through the api. The ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote namespace has methods to get information from CCNet on the build, like status, elapsed time, etc.

I would like to programmatically get the MSBuild task output from the CCNet api, but I haven't seen any methods for this. Is it at all possible? Or do I need to scan output files on disk or something? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement a custom IMergeTask and save the build log to database. In the end, it isn't possible to get the build log through the api.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you can get build log number, but if then you could retrieve the XML Log file from the Dashboard?

http://buildsrv/ccnet/server/local/project//build/log20100716115659.xml/XmlBuildLog.xml

(CC.NET Version 1.5.6804.1)

Comment: No, it doesn't seem I can get the log number through the api :(

Answer (score 1):

You can get all that through the CCNet API like:

```
var remoteCruiseManagerFactory = new CruiseServerClientFactory();

var client = remoteCruiseManagerFactory.GenerateRemotingClient("tcp://build:21234/CruiseManager.rem");

var history = client.GetModificationHistoryDocument("MyProjectName");

client.LostOfMoreGoodStuff();
```